# Zend_mm_heap corrupted and segmentation fault

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, segmentation-fault

I have PHP CLI script. Average running time of script is 20 minutes, but sometimes after some 10,15 minutes script stops and gives `segmentation fault` error.

If program is successfully done, I get error/warning message at the end in console `zend_mm_heap corrupted`

I have 8 threads and they are most of the time waiting for some outside response. When I do this without threads, again I have same errors, but then it needs more than 2hours this program to complete.

Picture below is `htop` command, for process view.
[image: server have 8 processors]

I need to mention that I have only user privileges on this server, and PHP 5.5 is installed

Comment: Do you have modpagespeed installed?

Answer (score 0):

Run `export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0`.

If you are using apache, add this command to `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

If you are using CLI, add this command to `~/.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`).